# warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast, segmentation fault

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, char, printf

I'm starting with C, coming from meta c language, basic, short times on PHP and HTML

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

compare(const void * a, const void * b){
    return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
} 

int main(){

    int arr_size = 10;

    int j;

    char array[arr_size][2];
    char str[50];
    char output[50];

    // fill the array with string and random integers
    for (j=0; j<arr_size; j++) {
         strcpy(str, "array");
         array[j][0] = str;       //i've should put *str
         array[j][1] = rand() % arr_size+1;
    }

    // print the array
    for (j=0; j<arr_size; j++) {
        strcpy(str, "");
        strcpy(output, "");
        sprintf(str, "%u", array[j][0]); // %u should be %s but return me segmentation fault
        strcat(output, str);
        strcat(output, " ");
        sprintf(str, "%i", array[j][1]);

        strcat(output, str);
        printf(output); printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n");

}
```

this is the full code, look at

```
array[j][0] = str;
```

and

```
sprintf(str, "%u", array[j][0]);
```

I need to put `*` before `str (*str)` to pass the warning message, but I have not declared any pointer. why this solution?

If I change `%u` with `%s` it returns me segmentation fault, what's the problem?

Comment: Read a good programming book about C (you'll get a better explanation than on a forum, because explaining C in a few minutes is impossible), and learn to use a debugger.

Comment: can you suggest me some references? actually i'm using geany :-)

Comment: @sataranjasvami, see http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info

Comment: http://www.cprogramming.com/ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language and the classical book by Brian W. Kernighan, Dennis M. Ritchie on *The C Programming Language*

Comment: `geany` is an editor (on Linux). The debugger is `gdb`. I strongly suggest compiling with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` and improving your code till no warnings are given.

Comment: `*str` is the same as `*(str + 0)` which is the same as `str[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

`array[j][0]` is `char`. You can't assign it array of chars. `*str` is simply the first char in `str`, so this assignment is valid.

From the same reason, you can't print it with `%s` - this specifiers is used to print nul-terminated strings, not single chars.

You also can't do `sprintf(str, "%s", array[j]);`, since it's not nul-terminated/

Comment: "can't assign it array of char", ok. I've used %c to see the results, all right. Which way do we have to solve the issue? I need string bidimensional array.

Comment: You might consider a pointer to a null-terminated array of `char` as a string. You coulde use `strdup` to create them. BTW, bidimensional array of strings would be easier in C++ as `std::vector<std::string>` so C++ could be easier for you.

Comment: it seems c++ is over for string, looking that